# Why does my mesh enlarge upon applying automatic weights?

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-weights

New to Blender and trying to rerig the original player model from the Unreal Engine 4. I apply automatic weights while selecting both my rig and the mesh, and after it applies, it enlarges. Files will be in the link for the .FBX import on the original model, the Blender save before weights applied, and Blender save after weights applied. Any help, or even a fix and re-upload, would be great, thank you.

[Blender and Model Files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/2ecd9bu72xqae/Blender_Weight_Issue)[image]

Comment: Your model is not parented correctly to the rig. Also, the rig's size isn't applied.

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues here.

## Unapplied scales

When rigging, every object's scale should be applied. if you select your rig and check its scale, you can see it isn't even nor equal to 1:
[image]

To correct that, select the object, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select Apply Scale.

## Wrong Parenting

Rigged models should be parented to your Rig object and the Armature modifiers should target that same Rig object. You have parented you model to a wrong object. And that wrong object also happens to have transforms on it, which influences your model, so we'll have to take care of that too.

1. Remove the armature modifier of your model.
2. With your model selected, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → *Clear Parent and Keep Transforms*.
3. Apply your model's scale.
4. Select your rigged model, then your Rig object, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → *Set parent to Armature Deform with Automatic Weights*.

Now everything should be fine. You'll just have to work out those weights.