# My Mesh gets big after I apply automatic weights

Tags: mesh, rigging, rigify

So in Blender I am trying to rig a Panda Bear. I rigged the Panda Bear and then I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select with automatic weights. When I did that the Panda Bear mesh got gigantic. I know that I havent rigged the Panda Bear right, but I just dont know what to do.

[image]
[image: Before and After Automatic weights]

By the way I looked at [Why does my mesh enlarge upon applying automatic weights?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134735/why-does-my-mesh-enlarge-upon-applying-automatic-weights) and I looked at the scale and the whole scale was all 1. With the wrong parenting text, I didn't know what to do because I couldn't find the blue wrench that would get me to the armature modifier.

Comment: If you select the panda object by clicking on it in the 3D view in Object mode, you should see the armature modifier on the R/H modifiers tab (blue spanner). To unparent an object, select it in the 3D view and use Alt-P > Clear Parent.

Comment: Your object is probably already parented to another object, so what you visually see is not its real size, it's its size as visually transformed by its parent. To fix that, first unparent the object (Clear and Keep Transformation), then parent it to the armature